# AWS Parameter store - how to access values using Linux in Node App

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

I am using the AWS parameter store to save enviroment variables such as my database password. I have also set up an IAM role so that the user can access these parameters.

What I am not sure about is how to access these values in my node JS application (also to note I am running Ubuntu).

I have tried to use the AWS-cli using the following the command to access my variables: `aws --region=ap-southeast-2 ssm get-parameter --name "DatabasePass" --with-decryption`

Unfortunately I get a list of help commands using this.

So I really have two questions:

1) How should I access my parameters, do I need to use the aws-cli as I am trying to do so above?

2) Once I manage to get these variables, how do I pass them to my node JS application? Do I need to run a bin/bash script on startup and set variables? I have never used bin/bash before, how should I approach this?

Any pointers to get me headed in the right line are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Ok so for anyone that happens to bump into this thread, I have managed to access my parameters in my Ubuntu server. First you need to install and configure the aws-cli using pip. Then you need to install the SSM agent as this does not come configured on Ubuntu (only on Amazon Linux). Then you will be able to access your parameters. Now the only question I have is how to pass these variables into my node app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getParameter() API call  of the Javascript SDK  to return your named parameter.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameters-property